# VIM: Know which command executed when a key pressed

Tags: vim

How do I know which command will be executed when I press a key, for example `<Leader>c`?

Comment: Do you want to see what keys you are typing or do you want the command description?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To see mappings use:

```
:verbose map <leader>c
```

Replace map by the corresponding imap, cmap, etc., as needed.

For Vim's built-in commands you'll need to use the help:

```
:help gq
```

See `:help context` for pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes if `map <keys>` is not enough you may use one of the following:

- `:debug normal <keys><CR>`: for normal, visual, select, operator-pending and insert/replace/virtual replace modes but not for ex/command-line mode. You will have to precede `<keys>` with something that enters target mode.
- `:set verbosefile=/tmp/verbose.log verbose=15<CR><keys>:set verbose=0<CR>`: for all modes it will procude a log of all commands executed in file `/tmp/verbose.log`. You will see errors if there is a recursive structure somewhere.
- Start vim with `vim -s <(echo '<keys>') -D`. It will enter debug mode immediately after vim starts, but you will have to skip all initializations manually.

These are all advanced debugging features and they are very time-consuming, but they may help where something more simple cannot.